# Compiling and Installing Chez Scheme on 64 Bit Arm?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, scheme, racket, chez-scheme

I tried to compile and install the Racket backend variant of the [Chez Scheme](https://github.com/racket/ChezScheme) compiler, since that now seems to support the aarch64 Arm 64 architecture, unlike the [mainline Chez Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) which is still restricted to 32bit ArmV6. I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 4 running 64bit aarch64 Raspbian (now renamed Raspberry Pi OS).

When I download the source code and try to `./configure`, I end up with error messages regarding the absence of the nanopass and zlib submodules.

How can I compile and install Chez Scheme onto 64 bit ARM?

Comment: Likely there's some undocumented package(s?) that you would first need to install with apt. I'd look into if nanopass and zlib are installed, and if they are this should be made an issue on their github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources for those components are in submodules. Depending on your Git version, you may have to check them out explicitly, using these shell commands:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

See `man git submodule` for details.

Comment: I did accept your answer last year, but just wanted to say explicitly that that answer did do the trick. I have managed to compile and install the ChezScheme backend of Racket using your solution.